# Can't get facebook user email address on log in

Tags: php, facebook, email, authentication

I have  the email permission in my application, but the code that I use, don't asks user to let me see his email.

I have been searching for a solution for a long time, and some people say that if I use:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?locale=en_US&fields=first_name,last_name,gender,birthday,email' );
```

Instead of:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
```

It will hеlp, but it's not true... the result is the same...

[image]

The code:

```
    <?php    
session_start();    
// added in v4.0.0    
require_once 'autoload.php';    
require 'functions.php';    
use Facebook\FacebookSession;    
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;    
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;    
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;    
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;    
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;    
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;    
use Facebook\GraphObject;    
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;    
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;    
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;    
// init app with app id and secret    
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'here is my id','here is my secret' );    
// login helper with redirect_uri    
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('here is my website link' );    
try {    
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();    
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {    
  // When Facebook returns an error    
} catch( Exception $ex ) {    
  // When validation fails or other local issues    
}    
// see if we have a session    
if ( isset( $session ) ) {    
  // graph api request for user data    
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?locale=en_US&fields=first_name,last_name,gender,birthday,email' );    
  $response = $request->execute();    
  // get response    
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();    
        $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');                  // To Get Facebook ID    
        $first_name = $graphObject->getProperty('first_name');    
      $last_name = $graphObject->getProperty('last_name');    
      $gender = $graphObject->getProperty('gender');    
       $birthday = $graphObject->getProperty('birthday');    

        $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    
          // To Get Facebook email ID    
    /* ---- Session Variables -----*/    
        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;               
      $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;    
      $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;    
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;    
      $_SESSION['gender'] =  $gender;    
      $_SESSION['birthday'] =  $birthday;    
    /* ---- header location after session ----*/    
    checkuser($fbid);    
} else {   
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();    
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);    
}    
?>
```

Comment: You are _not_ asking the user for `email` permission. You need to pass the permissions you want to ask for to `$helper->getLoginUrl()`.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper/5.0.0#get-login-url, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login/5.0.0

Comment: Okey, I got it ;) Thank you :*